# Getting error of "Invalid type for argument in function call." but not sure where to go from here. Suggestions?

Tags: solidity

Getting this full error in my solidity contract but not fully sure why. Could someone help point me in the right direction or to any docs that could help me?

The error I am getting is:

```
Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from type(struct CollegeGrades.Course memory[] memory) to struct CollegeGrades.Course[] memory requested.
```

the error is in my addStudent() function on this line:

```
students[id] = Student(_name, _age, _wallet, Course[]);
```

My solidity code is:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <=0.8.20;

contract CollegeGrades {
    // Struct to store information about a course
    struct Course {
        string name;
        uint credits;
        uint grade;
    }

    // Struct to store information about a student
    struct Student {
        string name;
        uint age;
        address payable wallet;
        Course[] courses;
    }

    // Mapping from student ID to student struct
    mapping(uint => Student) public students;

    // Counter to track the number of students
    uint public studentCount;

    // Event to be emitted when a student is added
    event StudentAdded(uint id, string name, uint age, address payable wallet);

    // Event to be emitted when a course is added
    event CourseAdded(uint id, string name, uint credits, uint grade);

    // Add a new student to the contract
    function addStudent(string memory _name, uint _age, address payable _wallet) public {
        uint id = studentCount++;
        students[id] = Student(_name, _age, _wallet, Course[]);
        emit StudentAdded(id, _name, _age, _wallet);
    }

    // Add a new course to a student's record
    function addCourse(uint _studentId, string memory _name, uint _credits, uint _grade) public {
        // Ensure the student exists
        require(students[_studentId].name != "", "Student does not exist");

        // Add the course to the student's record
        Student storage student = students[_studentId];
        uint courseId = student.courses.length++;
        student.courses[courseId] = Course(_name, _credits, _grade);
        emit CourseAdded(_studentId, _name, _credits, _grade);
    }

    // Calculate the GPA of a student
    function getGPA(uint _studentId) public view returns (uint) {
        // Ensure the student exists
        require(students[_studentId].name != "", "Student does not exist");

        // Calculate the GPA
        Student storage student = students[_studentId];
        uint totalCredits = 0;
        uint totalPoints = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < student.courses.length; i++) {
            Course storage course = student.courses[i];
            totalCredits += course.credits;
            totalPoints += course.credits * course.grade;
        }
        return totalPoints / totalCredits;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I want to thank you for posting the full contract; it made helping you **much easier**.

I modified your contract so it would work (While simplifying some code and keeping all the functionality and structures you implemented in your version of the contract.)

Hope this implementation works for you:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <=0.8.20;

contract CollegeGrades {
    // Struct to store information about a course
    struct Course {
        string name;
        uint credits;
        uint grade;
    }

    // Struct to store information about a student
    struct Student {
        string name;
        uint age;
        address payable wallet;
        Course[] courses;
    }

    // Mapping from student ID to student struct
    mapping(uint => Student) public students;

    // Counter to track the number of students
    uint public studentCount;

    // Event to be emitted when a student is added
    event StudentAdded(uint id, string name, uint age, address payable wallet);

    // Event to be emitted when a course is added
    event CourseAdded(uint id, string name, uint credits, uint grade);

    // Add a new student to the contract
    function addStudent(Student memory newStudent) public {

        require(newStudent.wallet == address(0), "Student with that wallet/address already exists !!!");

        // Geting student id
        uint id = studentCount++;

        // Setting all student values except courses
        students[id].name = newStudent.name;
        students[id].age = newStudent.age;
        students[id].wallet = newStudent.wallet;

        emit StudentAdded(id, newStudent.name, newStudent.age, newStudent.wallet);
    }

    // Add a new course to a student's record
    function addCourse(uint _studentId, Course memory newCourse) public {
        // Ensure the student exists
        require(students[_studentId].wallet != address(0), "Student does not exist");

        // Add the course to the student's record
        Student storage student = students[_studentId];

       // Adding new course to the array of all the Studen't Courses
        student.courses.push(newCourse);

        emit CourseAdded(_studentId, newCourse.name, newCourse.credits, newCourse.grade);
    }

    // Calculate the GPA of a student
    function getGPA(uint _studentId) public view returns (uint) {
        // Ensure the student exists
        require(students[_studentId].wallet != address(0), "Student does not exist");

        // Calculate the GPA
        Student storage student = students[_studentId];
        uint totalCredits = 0;
        uint totalPoints = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < student.courses.length; i++) {
            Course storage course = student.courses[i];
            totalCredits += course.credits;
            totalPoints += course.credits * course.grade;
        }
        return totalPoints / totalCredits;
    }
}
```

The main issue was that in this line of code, `Course[]` is a dynamic array. And assining it to storage is not yet supported in solidity.

```
students[id] = Student(_name, _age, _wallet, Course[]);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! Did not know I couldnt do something like this so will keep it in mind for the future

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a hard time doing it like that (i.e. an dynamic array of  structs Course in the struct Student).

I would keep the courses in a separated  mapping of student id to course id to course like so:

```
mapping(uint => mapping(uint => Course)) public studToCourse;
```

So you can call a course like so:

```
studToCourse[1][2]
```

where 1 is the id of the student and 2 is the course id.

Hope this design works for you!

Answer (score -1):

Where inserting into a struct, you have to use the storage. Otherwise, if you read from them, you can use memory.

```
Student storage student = students[id];
student.field = value;

Student memory student = students[id];
return student.name;
```